# Realm browser returns empty properties

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a User class which contains an Agency class.

```
class User: Object {
    dynamic var agency: Agency?
    ...
}
class Agency: Object {
    var name: String = ""
    ...
}
```

And when i print user.agency i get all the info, but when i print user.agency?.name i get an empty String.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` property of `Agency` needs to be `dynamic`.